# no puedo obtener el valor de un nodo padre en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

buenas tardes programadores tengo una duda muy grande y espero me puedan ayudar tengo una funcion llamada usu la cual saca valores de un div 
para ser exactos los saco con la valiable pedido el chiste esque si puedo sacar un hijo pero no puedo sacar el valor del padre pero el hijo lo consulto en base al padre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function usu(){

  var persona=document.getElementById("persona").innerHTML;
  var lista=document.getElementById("lista");
  var pedido=document.getElementById("lista-pedido");
  var radioid;
  var cantid=[];
  var produc=[];

  if(pedido.childNodes.length>1){
    var tamaño2=pedido.childNodes.length;
    for(var i=1; i<tamaño2; i++){
        var mesa2=pedido.childNodes[i];             
        cantid.push(document.getElementById(mesa2.id+"-1").innerHTML);
    }        
  }

  if(pedido.childNodes.length>1){
    var tamaño=pedido.childNodes.length;
    for(var i=1; i<tamaño; i++){
      var comida=pedido.childNodes[i];
      produc.push(comida.value);
    }
  }

  alert(cantid);
  console.log(cantid);
  console.log(produc);     
}
```

lo correcto seria hacer esto pero tampoco funciona me detecta a produc como un indefinido

```
 if(pedido.childNodes.length>1){
    var tamaño2=pedido.childNodes.length;
    for(var i=1; i<tamaño2; i++){
        var mesa2=pedido.childNodes[i];
         produc.push(mesa.value);
         cantid.push(document.getElementById(mesa2.id+"-1").innerHTML);
    }

 }
```

agradeceria su ayuda para poder sacar el valor del div con el valor de 227 gracias

Comment: No pongas el HTML como foto, sino como texto

Comment: es una foto de los elementos en el navegador

Comment: En el ultimo código, el de "lo correcto sería", no veo donde defines la variable mesa en el `produc.push(mesa.value)`, ¿será mesa2.value?

Comment: @costadark1212 se que es una foto del navegador, pero digo que mejor copies y pegues el texto para que sea mas facil reproducir el problema.

Comment: si asi es seria mesa2.value pero no me reconoce los valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentalo con `querySelectorAll()` asi:

```js
var pedido=document.querySelectorAll("div[id^=pedido]");    
var produc=[];
    
if(pedido.length>1){
    var tamaño2=pedido.length;
    for(var i=0; i<tamaño2; i++){
        var mesa2=pedido[i];            
        produc.push(mesa2.getAttribute("value"));
    }        
}
console.log(produc);
```

```html
<div id="pedido277" value="277">
    <div id="pedido277-1" value="1"></div>
</div>
<div id="pedido278" value="278">
    <div id="pedido277-1" value="1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: sos un genio amigo me funciono bueno no ocupe el sector all pero el getattribute me arreglo todo muchas gracias amigo

Comment: De nada @costadark1212 solo una cosa mas.  Veo que ya has hecho 4 preguntas pero no has marcado ninguna respuesta como aceptada.  Es una buena practica que aceptes las respuestas que te han ayudado para que la comunidad te siga apoyando.  Saludos.

Comment: disculpa amigo ahorita lo hago gracias te lo ganaste

Comment: listo amigo disculpa gracias

Comment: No hay problema.